# Can't embed text from js file in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js file. In this file there is defiend some texts. It will be include with that tag

`<script src="javascripts/resources.default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Here is the defined text.

```
menu_lacalize = {
    programm: "Programm",
    work: "Arbeit",
    nextPoint: "Naechster Punkt"
};
```

Ans the html file in which i am including this defined text :

```
<script type="text/javascript">menu_lacalize.programm;</script>
```

but it shows me nothing. In the console is no error and when i am alerting this it does not shows me the defined text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `document.write(menu_lacalize.programm);`.

Comment: `<yourelement>.innerHTML = menu_lacalize.programm;`

Comment: What do you expect it to do.. you're not doing anything with it? oO

Comment: hi again ;) this overrides me the hole html.. @AlexFilipovici

Comment: what happens when you do: `<script type="text/javascript">console.log(menu_lacalize.programm);</script>` do you see anything in your console?

Comment: It shows me Programm @intuitivepixel

Comment: What is the element where you would like to _embed_ the value?

Comment: a `<li>` @AlexFilipovici

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner, I strongly recommend you to consider jQuery for your current and future projects.

Comment: you might want to include this library in your future projects: http://www.webreference.com/programming/Globalize-Web-Applications19_Dojo/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<script src="javascripts/resources.default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('program').innerHTML = menu_lacalize.program;
</script>
```

Html markup

```
<ul>
  <li id="program"></li>
</ul>
```

Should result in

```
<ul>
  <li id="program">Programm</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<li>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(menu_lacalize.programm);
    </script>
</li>
```

Comment: I have written that document.write(...) overwrites my hole html code, why you answer then with that?

Comment: Which _hole_ html code...? Please make an effort and document your future questions properly. In your case, it's already becoming a pattern to have poor quality questions which leave space for a lot of guessing. I've added this answer in order to show you how to properly output the value. **Have you even tried** the solution I've posted?

Comment: **Yes** I have tried.. next time say pls define your problem better, and don't flame about it, and watch at the comments, there I have explained it.

Comment: _document.write(...) overwrites my hole html code_, that's not very likely, if you are using it right [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp).